# Callisto Custom Dialog Custom Styling for Windows App

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, callisto

Is there a way to customize the styling of the Callisto Custom Dialog other than the background? I want to change the font size and color of the title property of the Custom Dialog. Any suggestions without messing with the base style?

Reference: https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/wiki/CustomDialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CustomDialog's template calculates it's title's Foreground to a colour which contrasts with the Background and sets the FontSize to 26.6667:

```
<StackPanel Margin="13,19,13,25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" MaxWidth="680"> 
    <local:DynamicTextBlock Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Background, Converter={StaticResource ColorContrast}}" x:Name="PART_Title" Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="26.6667" FontWeight="Light" Margin="0,0,0,8" /> 
    <ContentPresenter Margin="0" x:Name="PART_Content" Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Background, Converter={StaticResource ColorContrast}}" /> 
</StackPanel>
```

If you want to change these you'll need to retemplate the dialog. You can copy the template from [Callisto's generic.xaml](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/blob/master/src/Callisto/themes/Generic.xaml) and then replace the Foreground and FontSize properties. You may want to use a TemplateBinding so you can set them on the CustomDialog when you call it:

```
<StackPanel Margin="9,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" MaxWidth="680">
    <callisto:DynamicTextBlock Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" x:Name="PART_Title" Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontWeight="Light" Margin="0,0,0,8" />
    <ContentPresenter Margin="0" x:Name="PART_Content" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Then set them to your own resources:

```
<callisto:CustomDialog Background="{ThemeResource MyCustomDialogBackground}" Foreground="{ThemeResource MyCustomDialogForeground}" Title="Lorem ipsum" Template="{StaticResource CustomDialogControlTemplate1}"></callisto:CustomDialog>
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems like the direction I want to head. Did you have any issues when copying the style over with any reference to "ThemeResource" in the template? I am not sure how to get these to work. Did you have to copy every "ThemeResource" setting over to your style?
 Example:
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource CustomDialogBorderThemeThickness}"/>

Comment: That actually worked. I just had to copy a few of the ThemeResources and set the correct directive to the one converter. Worked great! Thanks so much for your help.